# How to create a customized hovertemplate for plotly graph object parcats or express parallel categories

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

on hover on the nodes, how can I show the label of that node in hoverbox?

Comment: See this: [https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-text-with-a-hovertemplate](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-text-with-a-hovertemplate)

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners but looking for the parcats chart. I saw that parcats are made of no traces. correct me if I am wrong.